# How to overcome prediction results that are overestimated

Tags: r, predictive-models, prediction

I'm trying to create a prediction model for estimation of continuous variable based on about 35 Independent variables.My data set has circa 27k observartions.
Here is the summary of the the targeted continuous variable:

```
              Frequency Percent
(0,5]              2706  10.053
(5,10]             5226  19.415
(10,25]            4397  16.335
(25,100]           7142  26.533
(100,1e+03]        6465  24.018
(1e+03,1e+05]       981   3.645
Total             26917 100.000
```

I tried (by using R) Random Forest (RandomForest package),Linear regression, Conditional Inference Trees (ctree function in party package) but all of them have results that have a significant overestimation.
Here are the results of the prediction where I counted number of observations by thier distance from the actual values:
Any idea how can i balance the results?

[image]

Here are some views on the data:
The target variable is LTV for a user, I would like to predict LTV value after 180 days  based on users behavior of the first 7 days.
Here Is a summary fot the target variavle:

```
  vars     n   mean     sd median trimmed   mad  min      max    range skew kurtosis   se
1    1 26917 178.35 622.29  33.49   66.63 39.28 0.03 22103.73 22103.71 14.1   325.08 3.79
```

UPDATE:
Here are the distributions of the targeted variable (first)and the prediction (secound)results:
[image: targeted variable]
[image: prediction results based on the linear regression model that was the best]

Comment: 1. Could you show prediction $\hat y$ over true outcome $y$ plots? 2. Your $y$ covers orders of magnitude. Is there reason to assume that the $y$ should be modeled basically in a linear fashion over such a dynamic range? Or would a transformation like $\log y$ make sense? 3. What is the meaning of your target value ($y$)?

Comment: Thanks cbeleites, I updated the problem desc.I'm not sure that there is "a reason to assume that the y should be modeled basically in a linear fashion over such a dynamic range" but linear regression gave the best results so far.The log transformation is not helpfull in prediction as long as I don't have an interaction variables.Thanks for your help..

Comment: OK. So no log: I was asking because you basically present us a log axis here with your binning. With plot prediction over true/reference value I actually meant a scatter plot with $\hat y$ on the ordinate and $y$ as abscissa.

Comment: Just to be clear on the results table,it is not a log axe it simply the count of observations by thier predictide values distance from the true value.So 19385 oservations have predicted values that are overestimated for more than 50%.For exaple If my true value is 4 and predicted value is 16 than is overestimated by: step 1: (4-16=-12) step 2: (-12/4=-300%) so it will be part of the 19385 group..

Comment: You still use a description that is suited for log axes, not for linear axes, e.g. in the plots the range 10 - 100 is covered by 2 bins, as is the range 100 - 1000. The same is true for the residuals: Summarizing as percentage deviation (relative residuals) is useful for log axes (multiplicative relationship). For additive relationship, absolute residuals are typically far more appropriate, as these are what the linear models look at. BTW: if prediction is 16 and true value is 4, the model does overestimate, so your overestimation residual should be positive, not negative.

Comment: Got your point..But I still looking for an Idea how to center  the prediction results,right now the tails of true value - prediction values are too wide. It also seems that the target value is very skewed and has haevy tails - skew value of 14.0 and kurtosis of 325.0 and very big range.

Comment: Tess us more about your actual problem! Without that we can hardly advance! How did you reach the conclusion about overestimation? Based on a holdout sample? Otherwise? Tell us!

Comment: The conclusion about overestimation was based upon substructing the predicted values from actual values.One thing that I tried few minutes ago was using log transformation on the target variable as suggested by cbeleites.This took down the long tails of the overestimation by 20% but still the center of the diff% (+-0-10%) is only 6%..The results are on all the data and not an holdout sample.

Comment: I don't suggest log transformation, but you describe things here that typically do only make sense for log transformed data. Kjetil is right: without knowing more about your application and the way the data was generated, we cannot say much more.

Comment: ok, thank you.. I'll try to figure out how to present the data more clearly.